# I want to create start and end year variables for my repeated measurement with 11 observation for each subject of Extended Cox and JM model

Tags: r

I have rescaled the survival times by dividing them by 365.25 (since we observe patients over a long enough period for there to be leap years). However, I want to compare my survival times to the longitudinal times to see if they match up. So I can conclude that my last observation time in the longitudinal dataset is equal to the survival time. That's the best way I could think to deal with it. For me to do the comparison, I have to create starting and ending year variables for my longitudinal dataset to observe the last observational for the event to occur or be censored. I have tried several approaches but it is not working.

```r
# Create a reproducible dataframe
library(styler)
library(readr)
df2 <- (df2[1:25, ])
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'df2' not found
df2 <- 
  structure(
    list(
         year = c(0, 0.11538462, 0.5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 0, 0.11538462, 0.5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 0, 0.11538462, 0.5),
         armdia = c(82.5, 80, 80, 90.5, 84.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 86.5, 90, 80, 63.5, 84, 74, 71, 81, 80.5, 84, 81.5, 78.5, NA, 67.5), 
         armsys = c(143.5, 137.5, 132.5, 146.5, 141, 141, 141, 141, 141, 141, 141, 125, 135, 125, 117, 137.5, 124.5, 112.5, 136, 135.5, 146.5, 141, 121.5, 120, 124.5), 
         alloc = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
         id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, 25L), 
    class = "data.frame")

head(df2, 25)
#>         year armdia armsys alloc id
#> 1  0.0000000   82.5  143.5     4  1
#> 2  0.1153846   80.0  137.5     4  1
#> 3  0.5000000   80.0  132.5     4  1
#> 4  1.0000000   90.5  146.5     4  1
#> 5  2.0000000   84.5  141.0     4  1
#> 6  3.0000000     NA  141.0     4  1
#> 7  4.0000000     NA  141.0     4  1
#> 8  5.0000000     NA  141.0     4  1
#> 9  6.0000000     NA  141.0     4  1
#> 10 7.0000000     NA  141.0     4  1
#> 11 7.0000000     NA  141.0     4  1
#> 12 0.0000000   86.5  125.0     2  2
#> 13 0.1153846   90.0  135.0     2  2
#> 14 0.5000000   80.0  125.0     2  2
#> 15 1.0000000   63.5  117.0     2  2
#> 16 2.0000000   84.0  137.5     2  2
#> 17 3.0000000   74.0  124.5     2  2
#> 18 4.0000000   71.0  112.5     2  2
#> 19 5.0000000   81.0  136.0     2  2
#> 20 6.0000000   80.5  135.5     2  2
#> 21 7.0000000   84.0  146.5     2  2
#> 22 7.0000000   81.5  141.0     2  2
#> 23 0.0000000   78.5  121.5     3  3
#> 24 0.1153846     NA  120.0     3  3
#> 25 0.5000000   67.5  124.5     3  3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

My **dataset** has `year` variable which I want to create the start year and end year variable from to help in Cox Extend modeling

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# Convert survival times from days to years
df2 <- df2 / 365.25


# Data Wrangling using dplyr package
df3 <- df2[ , c("year", "armdia", "armsys", "alloc", "id")]

df3 <- df3 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(Start_Y = c(unique(df3$year), 8), 
         end_Y = 9) %>%
  select(-year)
df3
```

Comment: I don’t understand how `df2 <- df2 / 365.25` could be correct?

Comment: I used 365.25 because of the length year the study was conducted. This length of year was over a leap year hence I calculated the average length of a year is approximately 365.25 days to account for the leap year.

Comment: Not worried about the denominator. Worried about dividing an entire df by a number. Not all of the columns are in units of days.